# How can I export score data from a Flash Game (still in development)

Tags: flash, actionscript, export

The game will be on a school VLE (virtual learning environment) like 'Moodle'. Can you export to email? Spreasheet? Or can it only be done with php? Do not want to be spending weeks on it!

Answer (score 1):

You can't send emails directly. From Flash 10, it is possible to save file on the local computer, for this see the livedocs for FileReference class.

The best way for centralized data collection would be sending the data to your server. [Here is an  example for AS3 to PHP communication](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=169554) - you may have to tailor it a bit, but the basics are in there. You may want to use a database instead of the file in the PHP code, but that's an other question.

Good luck!

Comment: As an additional note, the post mentions the Actionscript 3.0 Cookbook, which is a great resource for some self contained working samples of various interesting things you can do in AS3.  Not an end all be all reference, but great if you're the type of person who learns by picking things apart and putting them back together until you understand what makes them work.